# jQuery confirm dialog not closing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery confirm dialog which is not closing on the `dialog("close")`.

```
$.confirm({
  title: 'Change From Date',
  content: url,
  buttons: {
    confirm: function() {
      $(this).dialog("close");
    },
    cancel: function() {
      $(this).dialog("close");
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [**minimal, complete, verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi Ajan - just following up. Was your question answered satisfactorily? If there is more we can help with, please add a comment below an answer, or edit your question to clarify what else you need help with. ***Otherwise, it would be great if you could choose a "best answer" (by clicking the checkmark beside the answer) to close out the question.*** If no answer provided helpful information, please add your own answer and select that as the best answer. You won't get any points for doing so, but that will close out the question. *Thanks!*

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way that I have found is the following:

```
jconfirm.instances[0].close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the selector you are using for the `.dialog('close')` method - instead of

```
$(this).dialog('close');
```

change it to:

```
$('.yourDialogClassOrID').dialog('close');
```

That is, whatever selector you use to *initialize* the dialog, use that selector for the `.dialog('close')` instruction:

E.G.

```
$( "#mydialog" ).dialog(); //initialize dialog
use:
$( "#mydialog" ).dialog('close'); //close dialog
```

Comment: Thanks for your response how could I specify Id or class to $.confirm.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. What is `$.confirm` ?  When using jQuery, `$()` is how you select any element, whether by ID or by className - for example: `$('#someID')` or `$('.someClass')` or `$('#mySelect')` or `$('.nutherTag')` etc. After selecting the element, you can then use a jQuery method on that element, such as **`$('#myButton').css('background': 'blue');`**  *Is that what you are asking?*

Answer (score 0):

I'm using jquery-confirm v3.3.4. the following code won't work for me:

```
jconfirm.instances[0].close();
```

The simpliest way to close the jconfirm dialog:

```
$('.jconfirm').remove();
```